# Unity, Android: how to set the aspect/scale of the game properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development, aspect-ratio

I've developed an Android game using Unity. And in the end I've faced the next problem:

Each level of my game has strict borders (like a box) along the sides of the screen. I've been developing the game with **aspect 9:16 (pic. 1)**. When I've built it and run on my phone (it's 9:19.5) I found out that **leftmost and rightmost parts of the levels are out of the screen** **(pic. 2)**.

How can I fix this, so the game fits every aspect ratio?

I've tried different solutions, but nothing satisfied me. I'm so desperate that I'm already agree to just scale it down from 9:16 so that it fits the WIDTH of the screen plus adding black bars at the top and at the bottom  **(pic. 3)**. Height is not so important in my game, but width is crucial. *Or is there some better solution?*

[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDATE 2:
My project's design (kinda grayboxing):
[image]
Here's how it looks **FINE** with different aspects in play mode:
[image]
And here's how it looks **POORLY** with different aspects in play mode:
[image]

Comment: It depends how you setup your Canvas and which constraints you added to your main views. Can you share that detail too?

Comment: @hardartcore I've updated the question with canvas info (i'm dealing with it for the first time (almost), so don't quite know how to set it up properly too). And what do you mean by "main views constraint"? I'll specify them as soon as I find out, sorry...

Comment: I mean the `Anchor Presets`. That's where the magic happens. Using those you declare how your `View` should be placed inside your `Canvas`. For example:  Top Right, Bottom Left, Stretch horizontal or vertical and etc. If it's ok with you it would be better to share a sneak peek of your design in order to help improving it.

Comment: @hardartcore I thought Canvas only affects UI rendering in the viewport, but not game objects in a scene. Anyways, I've updated the question with my design

Comment: Oh, so you are designing your level layout in 3d with cubes and trying to fit that it in your screen with a proper aspect ratio? Do you really need to design this with cubes? It seems like a 2d game to me.

Comment: @hardartcore I'm designing the game in 2d view using 3d objects. When I've started working on the project I haven't known how to create custom objects (2d), so using 3d objects was the obvious way. For now I think I've come too far to redesign this all and I fell like my passion began fading away...

Comment: If it's going to be a 2D game, no need to use 3D objects to design the level. It will be much easier to achieve the same design using Sprites and UI elements which will scale properly in every screen.

Comment: @hardartcore Then for the 2d approach a Sprite should be a part of Canvas in the hierarchy to scale properly or it could be just a regular image game object?

Comment: Yes, the white borders can be a simple Image inside the Canvas and the level should not be part of the Canvas itself. And the other part (levels, characters and etc) can be used as a 2D Sprite.

Comment: @hardartcore Well, the thing is when the level borders scale (come closer to each other for narrower screens, for example), the distance between the border and other game objects in the scene decreases, which is also crucial. All distances should stay the same. I've already come through this when tried to apply the script what would dynamically shift left and right border accordingly to the aspect. The border comes closer to "inner" level structure, and other game object no longer can traverse in between level border and inner level structure

Comment: My level structure should stay the same, cause it is a maze-like game

Comment: @hardartcore Look, I got an idea: what if I add black bars (just cubes) above and below my level structure, and then **child all the game objects** in the scene (_including background image, black bars, walls, etc_) **to a common parent**. Then I could **scale this common game object** (with all including level structure) **up or down until the left and right border of the level fits the screen sides**; and black bars will also appear, when it is scaled down. Could it work out?

Comment: It's more like a discussion now and it starts to turn out more like a game design idea. Maybe you can post this in Unity's forum and just paste the link to it there. It will be much better to continue there and others can help with an idea too.

Comment: @hardartcore Yeah, anyway, thanks for the response!

Comment: @hardartcore Sorry for continuing it here, but OMG, I think my idea works!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Maybe you can answer your own question with the solution so if it can help someone else with the samw issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way to achieve the goal.
I **added an empty game object** to the scene and **child'ed to it all the level structure**, plus adding two black bars (as simple cubes) above and below the level. With that approach I can scale that parent game object so that all the level structure *scales proportionally*.
All I have to do then is creating a script for scaling the parent game object according to the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Unity's camera assumes that games will be played in a landscape orientation. Therefore the amount of the game world that is rendered vertically will always be the same on any screen, regardless of aspect ratio. If you are restricting your game to be played only on mobile platforms, and only in portrait mode, then you will want to force Unity to do the opposite. You want the camera to always render the same width, and show a variable amount of height depending on aspect ratio. (Helpful hint: Develop with the smallest aspect ratio you expect, like 4:5, not 9:16. Configure all of the aspect ratios or resolutions you want to test in the dropdown menu at the top of the Game View. Switch between these for testing, and allow your UI and game view to expand out for taller aspect ratios. Otherwise your UI will probably run together on smaller aspect ratios. See my post on CanvasScaler [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/understanding-canvas-scaler-screen-match-mode-and-reference-resolution.524194).)

Anyway, to change the default camera behavior, you'll need to add a script to your camera. Something like this should do:

**Edit:** I modified the component to handle both perspective and orthographic cameras. Based on your game it appears you are, or perhaps should be, using an orthographic camera, which my previous answer did not handle. Also, there are no more properties on the component. Simply attach to a camera, then use the camera's properties as normal. Also, it now handles viewports, so it works with cameras that don't occupy the entire screen.

There is one known issue. With an orthographic camera, if you attempt to adjust the viewport to be greater than the entire screen size, something internal to Unity resets the projection matrix and overrides this component's behavior. To fix, simply toggle the component, or reload the scene or editor, anything that triggers the component to do its thing again.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class HorizontallyAlignedCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera _camera;
    private float _aspectRatio;
    private float _fieldOfView;
    private bool _isOrthographic;
    private float _orthographicSize;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        CachePropertiesAndRecalculate();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if(CameraPropertyHasChanged())
            CachePropertiesAndRecalculate();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _camera.ResetProjectionMatrix();
    }

    private bool CameraPropertyHasChanged()
    {
        bool hasChanged = (_aspectRatio != _camera.aspect
            || _fieldOfView != _camera.fieldOfView
            || _isOrthographic != _camera.orthographic
            || _orthographicSize != _camera.orthographicSize);

        return hasChanged;
    }

    private void CacheCameraProperties()
    {
        _aspectRatio = _camera.aspect;
        _fieldOfView = _camera.fieldOfView;
        _isOrthographic = _camera.orthographic;
        _orthographicSize = _camera.orthographicSize;
    }

    private void CachePropertiesAndRecalculate()
    {
        CacheCameraProperties();

        if(_camera.orthographic)
            RecalculateOrthographicMatrix();
        else
            RecalculatePerspectiveMatrix();
    }

    private void RecalculatePerspectiveMatrix()
    {
        float near = _camera.nearClipPlane;
        float nearx2 = near * 2.0f;
        float far = _camera.farClipPlane;
        float halfFovRad = _camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        // This is what aligns the camera horizontally.
        float width = nearx2 * Mathf.Tan(halfFovRad);
        float height = width / _camera.aspect;

        // This is the default behavior.
        //float height = nearx2 * Mathf.Tan(halfFovRad);
        //float width = height * _camera.aspect;

        float a = nearx2 / width;
        float b = nearx2 / height;
        float c = -(far + near) / (far - near);
        float d = -(nearx2 * far) / (far - near);

        Matrix4x4 newProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4x4(
            new Vector4(a, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, b, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, c, -1.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, d, 0.0f));

        _camera.projectionMatrix = newProjectionMatrix;
    }

    private void RecalculateOrthographicMatrix()
    {
        // This is what aligns the camera horizontally.
        float width = 2.0f * _camera.orthographicSize;
        float height = width / _camera.aspect;

        // This is the default behavior.
        //float height = 2.0f * _camera.orthographicSize;
        //float width = height * _camera.aspect;

        float near = _camera.nearClipPlane;
        float far = _camera.farClipPlane;
        float a = 2.0f / width;
        float b = 2.0f / height;
        float c = -2.0f / (far - near);
        float d = -(far + near) / (far - near);

        Matrix4x4 newProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4x4(
            new Vector4(a, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, b, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, c, 0.0f),
            new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, d, 1.0f));

        _camera.projectionMatrix = newProjectionMatrix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is something! I'm definitely going to try it, although this is, as you said, "big and scary" for me and gonna take a while to understand. Thank you very much!