# UNITY werid bars on the side

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

When I launch my unity program weird black bars load on the side here a picture i've tried changing the settings

[image]

Comment: Is this in the editor or a built version of the program? In the editor you can modify the aspect ratio used for the player window at the top.

Comment: its the built version

Comment: The black bars prevent your game from stretching and allow it to be seen in the resolution you picked. You might want to change target Aspect Ratio in Build Settings, use Canvas Scaler or change your main camera settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity, Android: how to set the aspect/scale of the game properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320065/unity-android-how-to-set-the-aspect-scale-of-the-game-properly)

Comment: where exactly can I find those settings

Comment: no this doesent awnser

Answer (score 0):

I found the awnser I just changed to exclusive fullscreen in project setting thx for trying to help